# XAML Slider Orientation not found

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a vertical slider in Xamarin.Forms. However I always get an error when I try this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
x:Class="Project1.DeviceInfoView"
Title="{Binding DeviceName}">
```

...

```
<Slider x:Name="slider"
Grid.Row="0"
Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
MaximumTrackColor="Gray"
MinimumTrackColor="#F7941E"
Minimum="0"
Orientation="Vertical"
Maximum="10"
Margin="10,0"
Value="{Binding SliderValue}"/>
```

The error I'm getting is "Error: Position 65:25. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'Orientation', or mismatching type between value and property."

I've tried creating a new project and building a vertical slider in that but that didn't work. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: There is no `Orientation` property for Slider

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42972823/vertical-slider-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: Just add a property "Rotation" to slider like Rotation="90" this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Ashray, If you want to achieve a vertical slider, just use `Rotation="90"` under the silder tab.

This is GIF of this running time.

[image]

```
    <StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
           BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=slider}"
           Rotation="{Binding Path=Value }"/>

    <Slider x:Name="slider"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
            MaximumTrackColor="Gray"
            MinimumTrackColor="#F7941E"
            Minimum="0"
            Rotation="90"
            Maximum="10"
            Margin="10,0"
    />
</StackLayout>
```